# Selenium Finding Elements via xpath

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, inspect-element

I am trying to login using selenium.

```
<form id="main-login-form" class="login-form form-container">
<input       name="username" id="username-input" placeholder="Username"   class="form-input"    autofocus="">
```

I am using the code.

```
  import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
```

import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

public class Tables 
{

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create a new instance of the html unit driver
    // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface, 
    // not the implementation.
    WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    // And now use this to visit Google
    driver.get("https://focus.nassau.k12.fl.us/focus/");


    // Find the text input element by its name
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='username-input']"));
    element.sendKeys("mcdonaldje");



    System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());

    // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element


    driver.quit();
}
```

I keep getting this error

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
 Unable to locate a node using //input[@id='username-input']
 For documentation on this error, please visit:      
 http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
 Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:59:12'
```

Comment: is the element in an `<iframe>` ?

Comment: No, it is a '<form>' and an '<input>'.

Comment: Can you change driver to FirefoxDriver for example and see if the issue is still occurs?

Comment: Same thing @drets .   Still getting the same error.

Comment: Scratch that! It opens FireFox to the default page. And then 'Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055' I think i need to watch more youtube on selenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it right!

```
In [16]: from selenium import webdriver

In [17]: driver = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.HTMLUNIT)

In [18]: driver.get("https://focus.nassau.k12.fl.us/focus/");

In [19]: el = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='username-input']")

In [20]: el.send_keys("mcdonaldje")

In [21]: driver.current_url
Out[21]: u'https://focus.nassau.k12.fl.us/focus/'
```

Comment: It doesn't like line 17.    `driver =  webdriver.Remote(DesiredCapabilities.chrome());`   Saying `webdriver` can not be resolved.

Comment: You are writing on Java bindings, my answer is written in python. I just shown you that there is no problem with finding element using xpath.

Answer (score 0):

After hitting the URL please wait for it load all the elements so that your web element is displayed on the page.
Any wait condition after driver.get("https://focus.nassau.k12.fl.us/focus/"); works well.